# SQL Query for month

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table where specific  information from a sql database is selected. At the moment, I need it to show information based on month as well as other things.
I have some code, but it currently doesn't show anything from the database..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE id_task = '1' AND id_child = $number AND DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%m-%Y') = '01-2016';";
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: What kind of field is `date_field`: `date`, `datetime`, `timestamp` or something different?

Comment: '01-2016'`;`"; ????? Typing mistake or error? Why have you put `;` in query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Table Name : transaction** 
Table Fields Values:

1. id_task = 1
2. id_child = 25
3. post_date = 2015-07-24 07:02:52

$sql = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE `id_task` = '1' AND `id_child` = '$number' AND MONTH(`post_date`) = MONTH('2015-07-24 07:02:52');

Comment: how would it be possible to include the year? lets say i wanted january 2016 as well as jan 2017.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MONTH()` function to filter with moth. Try the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE `id_task` = '1' AND `id_child` = '$number' AND MONTH(`date_field`) = MONTH('2016-01-01');
```

This query will get the records of **january 2016**

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transaction 
        WHERE `id_task` = '1' 
        AND `id_child` = '$number' 
        AND MONTH(`field_name_where_date_is_stored`) = MONTH('Date_which_you_want_search');
```

Note : Date format will be same.

Comment: @Sazzadur this a is solution please have a look.